# How to automatically generate report in PowerBi Service with REST Post API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

actually i m working on a react app and want to send data in api body from the front end to an existing powerbi service report. and what i want is that the new data (that i send in body) should replace the existing data in the existing powerbi report and should refresh it.

I have searched a lot in their docs. They have Post APIs to refresh report and to replace data of one report to another, but unfortunately i could not find any apis that take json data value and replaces the data of current report with the new data or creates a new report based on json data.

I'm working on a react app and want to send data in api body from the front end to powerbi service report. and what i want is that the new data (that i send in body) should replace the existing data in the powerbi report and should refresh it.

I just wanted to know is it even possible with powerbi service or with power automate?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this as you describe.

The API could save the data into a database that supports [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources) then use the [report export API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-report-in-group) passing a filter to reference the data you just inserted.

Or perhaps you can use a [Push Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/push-datasets).

Comment: thanks. but do you mean we can create a report from data we got from the SQL server via API call? pl let me know if we can do it.. also see if we can do this too or not? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293799/create-a-report-in-powerbi-using-api-and-embed-it-in-an-app