# Real time data report in powerbi service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

We have a react app where i want to embed a powerbi service report.

That report (kept in powerbi service) data will update the user interact with our react app's database.

I know there is a way-

if we connect that report with an SQL database source, and everytime that database source is refreshed, we will hit a powerbi provided 'refresh report api' and the updated data will be reflected in the embedded report..

But I want to know if there is any other more elegant way to achieve the same?

**Alternative way-**

also if there is a way to create a new report inside powerbi service just by hitting a powerbi endpoint with given json, and then embed that newly created report inside our application. that will be better.

as far as i have seen there docs they have apis to clone, delete, update a report but not to create one?

in case you know please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**my another related question is here for more reference** - [Create a report in powerbi service through APIs in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293799/create-a-report-in-powerbi-service-through-apis-in-react/75306548)

**also this community discuss -** https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Create-a-report-in-powerbi-service-through-APIs-in-React/m-p/3055794

Answer (score 2):

If you use a [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about) model the report will generate queries to your database when the user interacts with a report.  There will be no "refresh".

Comment: does it also work in embed mode. like we hv a report embedded in our react app, and user interact there w/ report?

Comment: Yes.  It works the same in embedded.

Comment: thanks. one more thing, i know there is rest API to create and delete datasets, also to clone, update, and delete a report. but have not found anything that can help us to create a brand new report from an existing dataset without manual interaction i.e through API? in case you know, please lead my way.

Comment: There's no REST API for that, but there is a Javascript API for it for use in embedded applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers